# Custom function only for edit mode, not add mode, in jqGrid

Tags: jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I have a jqGrid custom function as `editrules: { custom: true, custom_func: checkforduplicates, required:true }`

However, I want this function to be run only in add mode, not in edit mode. Is this possible ?

EDIT:- After answer below from Oleg, I changed code to below. However, the alert does not print. Not sure where I am going wrong.

```
colModel: [
            { key: true, name: 'id', editable: false, formatter: 'integer', viewable: false, hidden: true },
            {
                key: false,
                name: 'name',
                editable: true,
                editrules: {
                    required: true,
                    custom: function (options) {
                        // options have the following properties
                        // cmName
                        // cm
                        // iCol
                        // iRow
                        // rowid
                        // mode - "editForm", "addForm", "edit", "add", "cell" and so on
                        // newValue - the value which need be validated
                        // oldValue - the old value
                        // some additional properties depends on the editing mode
                        alert("mode is " + options.mode);
                        if (options.mode === "add") { // "add" for inline editing
                            var grid = $("#grid");

                            var textsLength = grid.jqGrid("getRowData");




                            var textsLength2 = JSON.stringify(textsLength);

                            alert("i am here");

                            var myAttrib = $.map(textsLength,
                                function (item) { return item.name });


                            var count = 0;
                            for (var k in textsLength) {
                                if (textsLength.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
                                    ++count;
                                }
                            }

                            var text, i;


                            for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                                text = myAttrib[i];
                                if (value === text) {
                                    return [false, " - Duplicate category name."];
                                }
                            }
                            return [true, ""];
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Free jqGrid supports old style `custom_func` with the options `value`, `name` and `iCol` and **the new style** validation. To use new style validation one don't need to specify any `custom_func` callback, but to define `custom` as the calback function with one parameter:

```js
editrules: {
    required: true,
    custom: function (options) {
        // options have the following properties
        // cmName
        // cm
        // iCol
        // iRow
        // rowid
        // mode - "editForm", "addForm", "edit", "add", "cell" and so on
        // newValue - the value which need be validated
        // oldValue - the old value
        // some additional properties depends on the editing mode
        if (options.mode === "addForm") { // "add" for inline editing
            // do the validation
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

In case of validation of Add form the `mode` property is equal to `"addForm"`, `options.iRow === -1`, `options.oldValue === null`, `options.rowid === "_empty"`. It's recommended to use `options.mode` to detect the editing (or searching mode) in free jqGrid because the values of other properties (`iRow`, `oldValue` and `rowid`) depends on the editing mode.

Comment: Is  'jqGrid  4.4.4 - jQuery Grid' a 'free jqGrid' ? Because when I use the above custom function, alert statement inside is not getting printed.

Comment: Is India a part of UK? It's depend on the time point. The license agreement of jqGrid was changed at the end of 2014 starting with publishing jqGrid 4.7.1 (see [the post](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?p=1438)). Based on MIT/GPL licenses of 4.7.0 I started **the fork** of 4.7.0, which I develop under the name "free jqGrid" in opposite to Guriddo jqGrid JS, which prices you can see [here](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334). Thus versions of jqGrid <=4.7 are free, but the name "free jqGrid" means the product which I develop. It's compatible to 4.x versions of jqGrid, but has many new features.

Answer (score 0):

For version 4.7 I use this method. Form for adding data class for the table. After that, special actions verified by the user are performed.

```
{
 name : "LOGIN", 
 index : "LOGIN", editrules: {
   required:true,
   custom:true,
   custom_func: dublicateUser
 } 

 ...

 {
  closeAfterAdd : true, 
  width : 500, 
  recreateForm : true,
  afterShowForm : function () {
    jQuery("#TblGrid_list_users").addClass('addMode'); 
  }

...

function dublicateUser() {
  var a;
  var login = jQuery('#LOGIN').val();
  var checkMode = jQuery('#TblGrid_list_users').hasClass('addMode');
  jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: {login:login, mode:checkMode},
    url: 'code/validate_user.php',
    async: false,
    success: function(data) {
      if (data == 'err') {
        a = 1;
      } 
      else {
        a=0;
      }
    }
  });
  if (a==1) {
    return[false,"error"];
  }
 else {
   return[true];
 }
}
```